# PYTHON : Make a list of 4 columns with 2 lists of 2 columns

Tags: python, list, csv, merge, psychopy

I'm really sorry if the question was already answered, I haven't found the correct topic ...
I'm on a project with Pavlovia and Pyschopy.

I want my participants to keep the cursor of the mouse inside a moving box (target).
I'm recording the data, and I want to:

1. record the position of the mouse and the target
2. calculate the distance between the mouse and the centre of the target during each frame
3. count how often the mouse was out of the box

The problem is between step 1 & step 2 :

- I can record in file "Mouse.csv" the position of the mouse (column for x and column for y)
- I can record in the file "Target.csv" the position of the target (column for x and column for y)

**BUT I can't have the positions in 1 file with 4 columns (Mouse x ; Mouse y ; Target x ; Target y)**

My problem is very similar as :

- [Convert 2 lists into list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24830804/convert-2-lists-into-list-of-lists)
- [Write 2 lists in 2 columns of CSV file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50324942/write-2-lists-in-2-columns-of-csv-file-in-python)

But it's not working correctly

The lists are looking like :

- Mouse : [['x1', 'y1'], ['x2', 'y2'], [...]]
- Target   :  [['xA', 'yA'], ['xB', 'yB'],[...]]

And I would like to get
[['x1', 'y1'], ['xA', 'yA'], ['x2', 'y2'],['xB', 'yB'],[...]]

But when I can join the lists I just have something like
[['x1', 'y1'], ['x2', 'y2'], ['xA', 'yA'], ['xB', 'yB'],[...]]   :-(

```
########## FILE 2 ###########
# data to be written row-wise in csv fil
data = MposList
#data  = MposArr   #######_csv.Error: iterable expected, not numpy.float64

# opening the csv file in 'a+' mode
file = open(mousefile, 'a+', newline ='') ;

# writing the data into the file
with file:
    # identifying header
    header = ['Mouse at x', 'Mouse at Y']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames = header)
    writer.writeheader()
    write = csv.writer(file)
    write.writerows(data)
    
########## FILE 3 ###########
# data to be written row-wise in csv fil
#Tdata = TposArr
Tdata = TposList
del Tdata[0]
del Tdata[0]
# opening the csv file in 'a+' mode
file = open(targetfile, 'a+', newline ='') ;

# writing the data into the file
with file:
    # identifying header
    Theader = ['target at x', 'target at y']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames = Theader)
    writer.writeheader()
    write = csv.writer(file)
    write.writerows(Tdata)
    
########## FILE 4 ###########
# data to be written row-wise in csv fil
#dataF = []
#dataF.append(mouse.getPos()).append(target.pos)
dataF = pd.DataFrame({'mouse x':mouse.getPos[0], 'mouse y':mouse.getPos[1], 'target x':target.pos[0], 'target y':target.pos[1])
#print(dataF)
#data  = MposArr   #######_csv.Error: iterable expected, not numpy.float64

## opening the csv file in 'a+' mode
#file = open("combiner.csv", 'a+', newline ='') ;

## writing the data into the file
#with file:
#    # identifying header
#    Fheader = ['Mouse at x', 'Mouse at Y', 'target at x', 'target at y']
#    writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames = Fheader)
#    writer.writeheader()
#    write = csv.writer(file)
#    write.writerows(dataF)

dataF.to_csv(combiner.csv, index=False)
```

The entire code is

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
This experiment was created using PsychoPy3 Experiment Builder (v2020.2.10),
    on February 03, 2021, at 21:08
If you publish work using this script the most relevant publication is:

    Peirce J, Gray JR, Simpson S, MacAskill M, Höchenberger R, Sogo H, Kastman E, Lindeløv JK. (2019)
        PsychoPy2: Experiments in behavior made easy Behav Res 51: 195.
        https://doi.org/10.3758/s13428-018-01193-y

"""

from __future__ import absolute_import, division

from psychopy import locale_setup
from psychopy import prefs
from psychopy import sound, gui, visual, core, data, event, logging, clock
from psychopy.constants import (NOT_STARTED, STARTED, PLAYING, PAUSED,
                                STOPPED, FINISHED, PRESSED, RELEASED, FOREVER)

import numpy as np  # whole numpy lib is available, prepend 'np.'
from numpy import (sin, cos, tan, log, log10, pi, average,
                   sqrt, std, deg2rad, rad2deg, linspace, asarray)
from numpy.random import random, randint, normal, shuffle
import os  # handy system and path functions
import sys  # to get file system encoding
import pandas as pd

from psychopy.hardware import keyboard

# Importing library
import csv



# Ensure that relative paths start from the same directory as this script
_thisDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
os.chdir(_thisDir)

# Store info about the experiment session
psychopyVersion = '2020.2.10'
expName = 'mouseANDtarget'  # from the Builder filename that created this script
expInfo = {'participant': 'sun', 'session': '01A'}
#dlg = gui.DlgFromDict(dictionary=expInfo, sortKeys=False, title=expName)
#if dlg.OK == False:
#    core.quit()  # user pressed cancel
expInfo['date'] = data.getDateStr()  # add a simple timestamp
expInfo['expName'] = expName
expInfo['psychopyVersion'] = psychopyVersion

## Data file name stem = absolute path + name; later add .psyexp, .csv, .log, etc
##filename = _thisDir + os.sep + u'data/%s_%s_%s' % (expInfo['participant'], expName, expInfo['date'])
filename = _thisDir + os.sep + u'data/%s_%s_%s' % (expInfo['participant'], expName, expInfo['date'])
mousefilename = 'mousePosition_' + expInfo['participant'] + '_' + expInfo['session']+'_' + expInfo['date'];
mousefile = mousefilename + '.csv'
targetfilename ='targetPosition_' + expInfo['participant'] + '_' + expInfo['session'] +'_' + expInfo['date'];
targetfile = targetfilename + '.csv'


# An ExperimentHandler isn't essential but helps with data saving
thisExp = data.ExperimentHandler(name=expName, version='',
    extraInfo=expInfo, runtimeInfo=None,
    originPath='C:\\Users\\melis\\Desktop\\untitled.py',
    savePickle=True, saveWideText=True,
    dataFileName=filename)
# save a log file for detail verbose info
logFile = logging.LogFile(filename+'.log', level=logging.EXP)
logging.console.setLevel(logging.WARNING)  # this outputs to the screen, not a file

endExpNow = False  # flag for 'escape' or other condition => quit the exp
frameTolerance = 0.001  # how close to onset before 'same' frame

# Start Code - component code to be run after the window creation

# Setup the Window
win = visual.Window(
    size=(3840, 2160), fullscr=True, screen=0,
    winType='pyglet', allowGUI=False, allowStencil=False,
    monitor='testMonitor', color=[0,0,0], colorSpace='rgb',
    blendMode='avg', useFBO=True,
    units='height') ################################################### size : 1024,769  // 3840,2160 & FullScreen=True
# store frame rate of monitor if we can measure it
expInfo['frameRate'] = win.getActualFrameRate()
if expInfo['frameRate'] != None:
    frameDur = 1.0 / round(expInfo['frameRate'])
else:
    frameDur = 1.0 / 60.0  # could not measure, so guess

# create a default keyboard (e.g. to check for escape)
defaultKeyboard = keyboard.Keyboard()

# Initialize components for Routine "trial"
trialClock = core.Clock()
mouse = event.Mouse(win=win)
x, y = [None, None]
mouse.mouseClock = core.Clock()
MposList=[]
text = visual.TextStim(win=win, name='text',
    text='default text',
    font='Arial',
    pos=(0, 0), height=0.1, wrapWidth=None, ori=0,
    color='white', colorSpace='rgb', opacity=1,
    languageStyle='LTR',
    depth=-3.0);
currentMousePos = visual.TextStim(win=win, name='currentMousePos',
    text='default text',
    font='Arial',
    pos=(0, 0.4), height=0.05, wrapWidth=None, ori=0,
    color='black', colorSpace='rgb', opacity=1,
    languageStyle='LTR',
    depth=-4.0);
TposList=[[],[]]
target = visual.Rect(
    win=win, name='target',units='pix',
    width=(800, 800)[0], height=(800, 800)[1],
    ori=0, pos=(0, 0),
    lineWidth=1, lineColor=[1,1,1], lineColorSpace='rgb',
    fillColor=[1,1,1], fillColorSpace='rgb',
    opacity=1, depth=0.0, interpolate=True)
currentTargetPos = visual.TextStim(win=win, name='currentTargetPos',
    text='default text',
    font='Arial',
    pos=(0, 0.6), height=0.05, wrapWidth=None, ori=0,
    color='black', colorSpace='rgb', opacity=1,
    languageStyle='LTR',
    depth=-4.0);
# Create some handy timers
globalClock = core.Clock()  # to track the time since experiment started
routineTimer = core.CountdownTimer()  # to track time remaining of each (non-slip) routine

# ------Prepare to start Routine "trial"-------
continueRoutine = True
routineTimer.add(120.000000)  ############################### default 10
# update component parameters for each repeat
# setup some python lists for storing info about the mouse
gotValidClick = False  # until a click is received
sameCount = 0
sameThresh = 300
sameWarning = 200
thisCol = "green"
# keep track of which components have finished
trialComponents = [mouse, text, currentMousePos, target,currentTargetPos]
for thisComponent in trialComponents:
    thisComponent.tStart = None
    thisComponent.tStop = None
    thisComponent.tStartRefresh = None
    thisComponent.tStopRefresh = None
    if hasattr(thisComponent, 'status'):
        thisComponent.status = NOT_STARTED
# reset timers
t = 0
_timeToFirstFrame = win.getFutureFlipTime(clock="now")
trialClock.reset(-_timeToFirstFrame)  # t0 is time of first possible flip
frameN = -1

# -------Run Routine "trial"-------
while continueRoutine and routineTimer.getTime() > 0:
    # get current time
    t = trialClock.getTime()
    tThisFlip = win.getFutureFlipTime(clock=trialClock)
    tThisFlipGlobal = win.getFutureFlipTime(clock=None)
    frameN = frameN + 1  # number of completed frames (so 0 is the first frame)
    # update/draw components on each frame
    # *mouse* updates
    if mouse.status == NOT_STARTED and t >= 0.0-frameTolerance:
        # keep track of start time/frame for later
        mouse.frameNStart = frameN  # exact frame index
        mouse.tStart = t  # local t and not account for scr refresh
        mouse.tStartRefresh = tThisFlipGlobal  # on global time
        win.timeOnFlip(mouse, 'tStartRefresh')  # time at next scr refresh
        mouse.status = STARTED
        mouse.mouseClock.reset()
        prevButtonState = mouse.getPressed()  # if button is down already this ISN'T a new click
    if mouse.status == STARTED:
        # is it time to stop? (based on global clock, using actual start)
        if tThisFlipGlobal > mouse.tStartRefresh + 10-frameTolerance:
            # keep track of stop time/frame for later
            mouse.tStop = t  # not accounting for scr refresh
            mouse.frameNStop = frameN  # exact frame index
            win.timeOnFlip(mouse, 'tStopRefresh')  # time at next scr refresh
            mouse.status = FINISHED
    if mouse.status == STARTED:  # only update if started and not finished!
        buttons = mouse.getPressed()
        if buttons != prevButtonState:  # button state changed?
            prevButtonState = buttons
            if sum(buttons) > 0:  # state changed to a new click
                # abort routine on response
                continueRoutine = False
    MposList.append(mouse.getPos())
    print("mmmmoooouuuuuussssee ", mouse.getPos())
    Mpos = np.array(MposList)
    MposArr = Mpos.ravel()
    print("MOUSE type ",type(MposArr)) ############ MposArr
    print("MOUSE dimension ",MposArr.ndim) ######### MposArr


    if len(MposList) > 2:
        if MposList[-1][0] == MposList[-2][0]:
            if MposList[-1][1] == MposList[-2][1]:
                #print('same')
                sameCount += 1
        else:
            thisCol = "green"
            sameCount = 0

    if sameCount >= sameWarning:
        thisCol = "red"
    if sameCount >= sameThresh:
        continueRoutine = False
        print(" mouse not moved for " + str(sameCount)+ " frames. Ending experiment")

    # *text* updates
    if text.status == NOT_STARTED and tThisFlip >= 0.0-frameTolerance:
        # keep track of start time/frame for later
        text.frameNStart = frameN  # exact frame index
        text.tStart = t  # local t and not account for scr refresh
        text.tStartRefresh = tThisFlipGlobal  # on global time
        win.timeOnFlip(text, 'tStartRefresh')  # time at next scr refresh
        text.setAutoDraw(True)
    if text.status == STARTED:
        # is it time to stop? (based on global clock, using actual start)
        if tThisFlipGlobal > text.tStartRefresh + 10-frameTolerance:
            # keep track of stop time/frame for later
            text.tStop = t  # not accounting for scr refresh
            text.frameNStop = frameN  # exact frame index
            win.timeOnFlip(text, 'tStopRefresh')  # time at next scr refresh
            text.setAutoDraw(False)
    if text.status == STARTED:  # only update if drawing
        text.setColor(thisCol, colorSpace='rgb')
        text.setText("Mouse not moved for: " + str(sameCount) + " frames")

    # *currentMousePos* updates
    if currentMousePos.status == NOT_STARTED and tThisFlip >= 0.0-frameTolerance:
        # keep track of start time/frame for later
        currentMousePos.frameNStart = frameN  # exact frame index
        currentMousePos.tStart = t  # local t and not account for scr refresh
        currentMousePos.tStartRefresh = tThisFlipGlobal  # on global time
        win.timeOnFlip(currentMousePos, 'tStartRefresh')  # time at next scr refresh
        currentMousePos.setAutoDraw(True)
    if currentMousePos.status == STARTED:
        # is it time to stop? (based on global clock, using actual start)
        if tThisFlipGlobal > currentMousePos.tStartRefresh + 10-frameTolerance:
            # keep track of stop time/frame for later
            currentMousePos.tStop = t  # not accounting for scr refresh
            currentMousePos.frameNStop = frameN  # exact frame index
            win.timeOnFlip(currentMousePos, 'tStopRefresh')  # time at next scr refresh
            currentMousePos.setAutoDraw(False)
    if currentMousePos.status == STARTED:  # only update if drawing
        currentMousePos.setText("Current pos: " +str(mouse.getPos()))

    # *target* updates
    if target.status == NOT_STARTED and tThisFlip >= 0.0-frameTolerance:
        # keep track of start time/frame for later
        target.frameNStart = frameN  # exact frame index
        target.tStart = t  # local t and not account for scr refresh
        target.tStartRefresh = tThisFlipGlobal  # on global time
        win.timeOnFlip(target, 'tStartRefresh')  # time at next scr refresh
        target.setAutoDraw(True)
    if target.status == STARTED:
        # is it time to stop? (based on global clock, using actual start)
        if tThisFlipGlobal > target.tStartRefresh + 10-frameTolerance:
            # keep track of stop time/frame for later
            target.tStop = t  # not accounting for scr refresh
            target.frameNStop = frameN  # exact frame index
            win.timeOnFlip(target, 'tStopRefresh')  # time at next scr refresh
            target.setAutoDraw(False)
    #TposList.append([target.pos[0],target.pos[1]])
    TposList.append(target.pos)
    #del TposList[0]
    print('taaaaggggeeett', target.pos)
    #print("target dimension ",TposList.ndim)
    TposArr = np.array(TposList)
    print("TARGET type ",type(TposArr))
    print("TARGET dimension ",TposArr.ndim)
    #print('0=',TposList[0],'et 1=', TposList[1],'et 2=',TposList[2])
    
    
    # *currentTargetPos* updates
    if currentTargetPos.status == NOT_STARTED and tThisFlip >= 0.0-frameTolerance:
        # keep track of start time/frame for later
        currentTargetPos.frameNStart = frameN  # exact frame index
        currentTargetPos.tStart = t  # local t and not account for scr refresh
        currentTargetPos.tStartRefresh = tThisFlipGlobal  # on global time
        win.timeOnFlip(currentTargetPos, 'tStartRefresh')  # time at next scr refresh
        currentTargetPos.setAutoDraw(True)
    if currentTargetPos.status == STARTED:
        # is it time to stop? (based on global clock, using actual start)
        if tThisFlipGlobal > currentTargetPos.tStartRefresh + 10-frameTolerance:
            # keep track of stop time/frame for later
            currentTargetPos.tStop = t  # not accounting for scr refresh
            currentTargetPos.frameNStop = frameN  # exact frame index
            win.timeOnFlip(currentTargetPos, 'tStopRefresh')  # time at next scr refresh
            currentTargetPos.setAutoDraw(False)
    if currentTargetPos.status == STARTED:  # only update if drawing
        Tpx = str(target.pos[0])
        Tpy = str(target.pos[1])
        targetPosition = 'Current target pos: x ='+Tpx+' et y = '+Tpy
        currentTargetPos.setText(targetPosition)


################### count(mouse x) pour compter le nombre de ligne (pour la moyenne)


    # check for quit (typically the Esc key)
    if endExpNow or defaultKeyboard.getKeys(keyList=["escape"]):
        core.quit()

    # check if all components have finished
    if not continueRoutine:  # a component has requested a forced-end of Routine
        break
    continueRoutine = False  # will revert to True if at least one component still running
    for thisComponent in trialComponents:
        if hasattr(thisComponent, "status") and thisComponent.status != FINISHED:
            continueRoutine = True
            break  # at least one component has not yet finished

    # refresh the screen
    if continueRoutine:  # don't flip if this routine is over or we'll get a blank screen
        win.flip()

# -------Ending Routine "trial"-------
for thisComponent in trialComponents:
    if hasattr(thisComponent, "setAutoDraw"):
        thisComponent.setAutoDraw(False)
# store data for thisExp (ExperimentHandler)





###############################################################
x, y = mouse.getPos()
buttons = mouse.getPressed()
thisExp.addData('last x', x)
thisExp.addData('last y', y)
#thisExp.addData('mouse.leftButton', buttons[0])
#thisExp.addData('mouse.midButton', buttons[1])
#thisExp.addData('mouse.rightButton', buttons[2])
#thisExp.addData('mouse.started', mouse.tStart)
#thisExp.addData('mouse.stopped', mouse.tStop)
thisExp.addData('x', MposList)
thisExp.nextEntry()
print('MOUSE LIST', MposList)
print('MOUSE ARRAY', MposArr)
#print('last mouse position', MposList[-1][0],  MposList[-1][1])
print('last mouse position', MposList [-1][0],  MposList[-1][1])
print('TARGET LIST', TposList)
print('TARGET ARRAY', TposArr)
#thisExp.addData('text.started', text.tStartRefresh)
#thisExp.addData('text.stopped', text.tStopRefresh)
#thisExp.addData('currentMousePos.started', currentMousePos.tStartRefresh)
#thisExp.addData('currentMousePos.stopped', currentMousePos.tStopRefresh)
thisExp.addData('target.started', target.tStartRefresh)
thisExp.addData('target.stopped', target.tStopRefresh)
###################################################################################################


########## FILE 2 ###########
# data to be written row-wise in csv fil
data = MposList
#data  = MposArr   #######_csv.Error: iterable expected, not numpy.float64

# opening the csv file in 'a+' mode
file = open(mousefile, 'a+', newline ='') ;

# writing the data into the file
with file:
    # identifying header
    header = ['Mouse at x', 'Mouse at Y']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames = header)
    writer.writeheader()
    write = csv.writer(file)
    write.writerows(data)
    
########## FILE 3 ###########
# data to be written row-wise in csv fil
#Tdata = TposArr
Tdata = TposList
del Tdata[0]
del Tdata[0]
# opening the csv file in 'a+' mode
file = open(targetfile, 'a+', newline ='') ;

# writing the data into the file
with file:
    # identifying header
    Theader = ['target at x', 'target at y']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames = Theader)
    writer.writeheader()
    write = csv.writer(file)
    write.writerows(Tdata)
    
########## FILE 4 ###########
# data to be written row-wise in csv fil
#dataF = []
#dataF.append(mouse.getPos()).append(target.pos)
dataF = pd.DataFrame({'mouse x':mouse.getPos[0], 'mouse y':mouse.getPos[1], 'target x':target.pos[0], 'target y':target.pos[1])
#print(dataF)
#data  = MposArr   #######_csv.Error: iterable expected, not numpy.float64

## opening the csv file in 'a+' mode
#file = open("combiner.csv", 'a+', newline ='') ;

## writing the data into the file
#with file:
#    # identifying header
#    Fheader = ['Mouse at x', 'Mouse at Y', 'target at x', 'target at y']
#    writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames = Fheader)
#    writer.writeheader()
#    write = csv.writer(file)
#    write.writerows(dataF)

dataF.to_csv(combiner.csv, index=False)

# Flip one final time so any remaining win.callOnFlip()
# and win.timeOnFlip() tasks get executed before quitting
win.flip()

# these shouldn't be strictly necessary (should auto-save)
thisExp.saveAsWideText('filename'+'.csv', delim='auto')
thisExp.saveAsPickle(filename)
logging.flush()
# make sure everything is closed down
thisExp.abort()  # or data files will save again on exit
win.close()
core.quit()
```

I think I'm not understanding how bi-dimentionnal lists are working, but I've read a lot of courses and tutorial, and I don't have the trick with it :(

THANK YOU

EDIT :
Here is the result I have with :
`[item for sublist in zip(Mouse, Target) for item in sublist]`

[image: Almost done !]

So, I think, I need   `[['x1', 'y1', 'xA', 'yA'], ['x2', 'y2','xB', 'yB'],[...]]`

EDIT 2 :
It worked thanks to Akshay Sengal !

[image: result of the good code]

Comment: Try using `zip` with list flattening as I show below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `zip` and then flatten it to get items back. You can zip the 2 lists element-wise (corresponding elements of both lists added to a tuple together.

Post that you can use `[item for sublist in list for item in sublist]` which lets you [flatten](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists) and break the tuples into corresponding items.

List this -

```
Mouse = [['x1', 'y1'], ['x2', 'y2']]
Target = [['xA', 'yA'], ['xB', 'yB']]

[item for sublist in zip(Mouse, Target) for item in sublist]
```

```
[['x1', 'y1'], ['xA', 'yA'], ['x2', 'y2'], ['xB', 'yB']]
```

---

**EDIT:**

Based on your updated question, you can do this -

```
Mouse = [['x1', 'y1'], ['x2', 'y2']]
Target = [['xA', 'yA'], ['xB', 'yB']]

out = [i+j for i,j in zip(Mouse, Target)]
out
```

```
[['x1', 'y1', 'xA', 'yA'], ['x2', 'y2', 'xB', 'yB']]
```

Comment: Hello Akshay, 

Thank you, It's a better result than what I did with zip ^^"

`zip(Mouse,Target)
<zip object at 0x000001DF0AF95788>
map(list,zip(Mouse,Target))
<map object at 0x000001DF4F1A2630>`

But, I was wrong about what I needed :/ I'll update my question to show you.
I think I understood, I'll try something and come back to you

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Do mark the answer if it helped you and do upvote it if it’s well written to your liking. This encourages me to help solve your future questions :)

Answer (score 0):

just for the ones who want to test my code, the combined file worked with
**i[0],i[1],j[0],j[1]**  instead of **i+j**

```
#data to be written row-wise in csv file
dataF = [[i[0],i[1],j[0],j[1],k,abs(i[0]-j[0]),abs(i[1]-j[1])] for i,j,k in zip(MposList,Tdata,mIOt)]
```

the type/dimension of the lists wasn't working with the normal code, I had an addition of the x's and addition of the y's